# JavaCC - JSON Parsing

Tags: json, parsing, javacc

I want to using this JSON Parser
https://github.com/inqwell/json

and I compiled JSON.jj
But it doesn't have main method, so I tried write main method
however not work
I wrote main method like this

public class JSONParserMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReader fr;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("test.json");

        JSON<Map<String, Object>, List<Object>> parser = new JSON<Map<String, Object>, List<Object>>(fr);

        parser.parse(new NothingHandler());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static class NothingHandler extends DefaultHandler<Map<String, Object>, List<Object>> {}
```

}

this code is refer to a JSONTest.java
but parse method is return null
how can I write main method for "test.json"?

"test.json" is here

> {"root": {"data": 
>   [
>    [
>      {
>        "a": "String AA"
>      },
>      "String A2"
>    ],
>    {
>      "pi": 3.142,
>      "c": 1234567.9
>    },
>    {
>      "cat": "Stuff on my cat",
>      "a3": "",
>      "fooinstance": {
>        "typedef": "xmltest_types_FooType",
>        "Comment": "Comments & a ' character, berslackers of the world unite",
>        "HotFlag": "M",
>        "LastUpdated": null,
>        "ProductId": null,
>        "Rate": 1.235,
>        "Big": 3456789.01
>      },
>      "keyK": {
>        "HotFlag": null,
>        "__key": "K",
>        "__descriptor": "xmltest.types.FooType"
>      }
>    }
>   ], ...........(skip)

Comment: Are you sure you need a JavaCC-based parser for JSON? Not a ready-to-use library like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? Just asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `NothingHandler` is causing `null` to be returned. Use the `BasicHandler` instead.  Also you will need to change the line

```
parser.parse(new NothingHandler());
```

to

```
Object result = parser.parse(new BasicHandler());
// do something with result
```